# Selecting multiple rows from the same table with common column?

Tags: sql, oracle

Have the following hypothetical table User_Mail_Info in Oracle DB

```
| User_Id | Mail_DL | DLId     |.....
--------------------------------
|  User1  |  DLA    |   1      |
|  User1  |  DLB    |   2      |
|  User2  |  DLA    |   1      |
|  User2  |  DLB    |   2      |
|  User2  |  DLC    |   3      |......
|  User3  |  DLA    |   1      |
|  User3  |  DLC    |   2      |
|  User3  |  DLB    |   3      |......
```

Primary key is User_Id,Mail_DL,DLId. There are other columns with the table as well.

How to retrieve the UserId ,given the list of (Mail_DL and DL Id) ?

Note: Mail_DL and DL_Id are not directly related. This is just hypothetical data

For eg.
Input is

- (DLA, 1), (DLB,2) - Output has to be User1
- (DLA, 1), (DLB,2), (DLC,3) - Output has to be User2
- (DLA, 1), (DLC,2), (DLB, 3) - Output has to be User3

Thanks in advance for helping out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use aggregation and filtering.  For the first example:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having sum(case when mail_id = 'DLA' and dlid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when mail_id = 'DLB' and dlid = 2 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       count(*) = 2;
```